# Assigning specific color to a range of values in heatmap using pheamap

Tags: r, heatmap, pheatmap

I want to make a heatmap using pheatmap where if anything is between -1 to -0.5 it should be darkgreen and anything between -0.5 to -0.10 as lightgreen and anything between -0.10 to 0 as white. Similarly 0 to 0.10 as white, 0.10 to 0.5 as light purple and anything between 0.5 to 1 as purple. I also don't want to scale my data and no clustering. I have this code so far in R:

```
0.85    0.63    0.61    0.60    0.53    0.23    0.20    0.15    0.12    0.08    0.04    -0.05   -0.08   -0.19   -0.34   -0.56   -0.78
0.75    0.54    0.51    0.50    0.45    0.41    0.35    0.12    0.08    0.04    -0.01   -0.07   -0.15   -0.45   -0.51   -0.57   -0.68

df <- read.table("test.txt", header = FALSE, sep = "\t")
pheatmap(as.matrix(df),
         scale="none",
         cluster_rows = FALSE,
         cluster_cols = FALSE,
         annotation_names_col = FALSE,
         show_colnames= FALSE,
         color = colorRampPalette(colors = c("darkgreen","white","purple"))(200),
         main = "A3SS",
         border_color = NA,
         fontsize_row=10
)
```

How can I use breaks in pheatmap to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the breaks and build the color palette correctly - this should do the job if you really want 200 colors (if not see the next section):

```
library(pheatmap)

 # dummy data
df <- data.table::fread("0.85    0.63    0.61    0.60    0.53    0.23    0.20    0.15    0.12    0.08    0.04    -0.05   -0.08   -0.19   -0.34   -0.56   -0.78
0.75    0.54    0.51    0.50    0.45    0.41    0.35    0.12    0.08    0.04    -0.01   -0.07   -0.15   -0.45   -0.51   -0.57   -0.68")

# make the color pallete
clrsp <- colorRampPalette(c("darkgreen", "white", "purple"))   
clrs <- clrsp(200) 

breaks1 <- seq(-1, 1, length.out = 200)

pheatmap(as.matrix(df),
         scale="none",
         cluster_rows = FALSE,
         cluster_cols = FALSE,
         annotation_names_col = FALSE,
         show_colnames= FALSE,
         color =  clrs,
         main = "A3SS",
         breaks = breaks1,
         fontsize_row=10)
```

[image]

in case that you want just to work with five color and cut exactly at the informed values, one option to source from a already made pallet of the RColorBrewer packages:

```
breaks2 <- c(-1, -0.5, -0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 1)

pheatmap(as.matrix(df),
         scale="none",
         cluster_rows = FALSE,
         cluster_cols = FALSE,
         annotation_names_col = FALSE,
         show_colnames= FALSE,
         color =  rev(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(5, name = "PiYG")),
         main = "A3SS",
         breaks = breaks2,
         fontsize_row=10)
```

[image]

Alternatively you can inform color in a vector but there is no explicite light purple from text anyhow you could you hex color codes to be more precise then just "light"/"dark":

```
pheatmap(as.matrix(df),
         scale="none",
         cluster_rows = FALSE,
         cluster_cols = FALSE,
         annotation_names_col = FALSE,
         show_colnames= FALSE,
         color =  c("darkgreen","lightgreen","white","darkorchid1","purple"),
         main = "A3SS",
         breaks = breaks2,
         fontsize_row=10)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi I like this approach, is there a way I can do more gradation in this keeping the scale same? like more granular?

Comment: hi, in the first example you see usage of 200 color shades - the second and third approach both use 5. In case of wanting to use more colors for the last two you would have to increase the number of breaks (aka. breaks2) - i.e. c(-1, -0.5, -0.3, -0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 1) for 7 breaks and choose 7 instead for five colors. For colors you can simply use the hexacode (https://htmlcolorcodes.com/) or maybe you find what you need in the build in colors. This is a good link for starting with colors in R http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/colors-in-r